# Need help proving the following:

Tags: proof-writing

Any help at all would be great. Thank you very much.

For all $m,n,p \in \mathbb{Z}$, If $p<0$ and $mp<np$ then  $n<m$

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681706/if-m-n-and-p-0-then-np-mp)?

Comment: @2012ssohn They're a bit different.

Comment: @user3182252 It's extremely similar to what you're asking, with a change of variables. See my answer below.

Comment: @user3182252 You might want to consider accepting one answer to each of the questions you've asked. To accept an answer (you can accept only one answer per question asked), just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the question you would like to accept. You earn $2$ reputation points each time you accept an answer. You will soon (if not already) be able to *upvote* as many answers as you'd like, too.

Answer (score 0):

To proof: For all $m,n,p\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $p<0$ and $mp<np$ then $n<m$.

If $p<0$, then $\exists$ some $y$ such that $y=-p$. Then, $$mp<np$$Becomes $$-my<-ny$$Dividing by $y$ gives $$-m<-n$$Dividing by $-1$ changes the inequality sign, so $n<m$.